# Finding All CSS Rules (including "invalid rules") Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use document.styleSheets to add a shim for CSS calc functionality.

Basically I am looping over each stylesheet and it's subsequent rules and looking for calc to occur somewhere, and doing the calculation in JavaScript and applying it to the associated element.

This is MUCH faster than looping over every element on the page and trying to find if it has a failed calc rule, but the problem is I do not see a way to pull in errored CSS rules through this method. Both rules and cssRules arrays contain only CSS that the browsers considers valid.

My question is this, is there a way to get these invalid CSS values through this method?

The code I am using is below, and works, but only on browsers that support calc anyways, which is useless to me.  I need to be able to get ALL of the css rules as they appeared in the loaded CSS document in order to make this work.

Is this possible or am I barking up an imaginary fantasy tree of cross-browser calc awesomeness?

```
calcShim = function(){
    var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
    var calcs = [];
    for (var i=0, j=stylesheets.length; i<j; i++){
        var stylesheet = stylesheets[i];
        var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;
        if (rules && rules.length > 0){
            for (var k=0, l=rules.length; k<l; k++){
                var rule = rules[k];
                var ruleText = String(rule.cssText);
                if (ruleText.match("calc")){
                    calcs.push(ruleText);
                };
            };
        }
    };

    for (var i=0, j=calcs.length; i<j; i++){
        var string = calcs[i];
        var reference = calcs[i].match(/^[^{]{1,}/g)[0];

        var objects = $(reference);
        for (var k=0, l=objects.length; k<l; k++){
            var object = $(objects[k]);
            var parent = object.parent();

            if  (parent.is(":visible")){
                var parentWidth = parseInt(parent.width());
                var percent = parseInt(string.match(/(?:calc\()([0-9]{1,3})(?=%)/)[1])/100;
                var operator = string.match(/(?:calc[^)]{1,})([\+\-\*\/])(?=\s[0-9]{1,3}px)/)[1];
                var value = parseInt(string.match(/(?:calc[^)]{1,}[\+\-\*\/]\s)([0-9]{1,3})(?=px)/)[1]);

                var mathString = (parentWidth*percent) + " " + operator + " " + value;
                var result = eval(mathString);
                object.css({"width": result});
            }
        };
    };
};
```

I am aware this code could be better/cleaner, I was just trying to come up with a proof of concept.

Comment: Possibly, request the stylesheet with ajax and the text datatype then parse it as raw text, rule by rule? could potentially be inefficient though depending on the size.

Comment: Possibly even have your server do that part and just make an ajax request to the server, if it's too inefficient to do it in the browser. Then you can at least cache it globally and only do it once every n requests or hours.